# react <i> tag onClick triggers only after double Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, clipboard

I intend to use the "CopyToClipboard" package so that when you click on the  tag below, something is saved to the clipboard. This also works currently, but only if you double click on the  tag. How do I solve it that I only have to click once and it appears directly on the clipboard?

```
const Card = (props: ICardProps) => {
  // // State of Clipboard
  const [clipboard, setClipboard] = useState("");
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

  const cpyClip = () => {
    setClipboard(`short.url/${props.shortUrl.shortUrl}`);
    setCopied(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <div className="card-section">
          <div className="icon-controller">
            <CopyToClipboard
              text={clipboard}
              onCopy={() => {
                setCopied(true);
              }}
            >
              <span></span>
            </CopyToClipboard>

            <CopyToClipboard text={clipboard} onCopy={() => setCopied(copied)}>
              <i onClick={cpyClip} className="far fa-copy"></i>
            </CopyToClipboard>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're only setting `clipboard`, the string to copy, when someone clicks on the `<i>`.

Try something like

```
const Card = (props: ICardProps) => {
  const url = `short.url/${props.shortUrl.shortUrl}`;
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="card-body">
      <div className="card-section">
        <div className="icon-controller">
          <CopyToClipboard text={url} onCopy={() => setCopied(true)}>
            <i className="far fa-copy" />{copied ? 'Copied' : null}
          </CopyToClipboard>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

instead.